# How to react to model changes?

Tags: wpf

I would like to know what the "best practice" is for the following scenario:-

I have a viewmodel that exposes a model via a public property. The model is a C# class (separate from the viewmodel) that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. In my view I bind textboxes to various properties of that model.

I would like to execute a method in my viewmodel whenever the model's property values change. What would be a good approach? My thoughts:-

- Have the viewmodel pass a delegate to the model which gets called by the property's setter, or
- Have the viewmodel subscribe to the model's PropertyChanged event?

The first feels like I would be contaminating what is essentially a POCO model, while the second option somehow doesn't feel quite right either - subscribing to an event that is normally used by views/binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the `ViewModel` subscribe to the Model's `PropertyChanged` event

The [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface is meant to be used for any object that needs to raise property change notifications, not just objects that get bound to the UI. I use it all the time for non-UI purposes :)

Comment: Great - common sense was telling me this was the way to go, so good to get confirmation.